# How to create a s3 trigger programmatically to invoke a lambda function in a different lambda function itself

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, boto3

How to create a s3 trigger programmatically in a lambda function to invoke another lambda function whenever a specific file is uploaded into s3 bucket. I tried using putbucketnotification configuration api of boto 3.Here I used this API in a lambda function which will create a s3 trigger for another lambda function. But the problem with this API is it is replacing the existing triggers with new one and not adding new triggers to the existing one and also I cant add both prefix and suffix ,can add only either prefix or suffix to the trigger. So is there any other way to add s3 trigger in the lambda function like with any other api in. I will share my code

```
import boto3


def lambda_handler(event, context):
    client1 = boto3.client('lambda')
    client = boto3.client(
                    's3',
                    aws_access_key_id='access key',
                    aws_secret_access_key='secret key')


    response = client.put_bucket_notification_configuration(
    Bucket='bucketname',
    NotificationConfiguration= {'LambdaFunctionConfigurations':[{'LambdaFunctionArn': 'lambdafunction_arn', 'Events': ['s3:ObjectCreated:*'], "Filter": {
        "Key": {
          "FilterRules": [
            {
              "Name": "prefix",
              "Value": "folder1/"
            }
          ]
        }}}]})
```

Comment: First you get existing notifications, update it, and then replace.

Comment: Are you wanting to trigger multiple AWS Lambda functions from the same Amazon S3 bucket and Prefix? Or is this for a different prefix to any triggers that already exist?